# VSCode Unity Cant get working suggestion (even Debug.Log isnt autocompleting)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

So I tried to uninstall VSCode, deleting all its files and folders and following guides to reset it.
I have dotnet sdk installed, and in VSC terminal dotnet command works
I have C# Extension in VSCode installed.
In Unity I select VSCode as default script editor, and regenerate all .csproj files. They show up in VSCode when I open a script.

I create new script, open it, and start typing "De" to see if "Debug.Log" gets suggested. Its like VSCode never heard of it
[image: DebugL gets offered to autocomplete with lock]
What am I doing wrong?
Windows 10

Comment: @AdamKaczmarski In my original post I say I have C# code extension added already.
I found screenshots where "Debug.Log" gets not only autocompleted, but also described as being void function and other stuff. Here the Debug.Log is treated as nonexistent. 
Maybe its not intellisense issue here, my terminology may be flawed. The issue is still real

Comment: Did you go through the [official setup](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity)? Also make sure that the [`Visual Studio Code`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.ide.vscode.html) package is installed in your project via the PackageManager

Comment: @derHugo Visual Studio Code is installed in packageManager v 1.2.4. Unity installation is fresh aswell.
I went trough official setup, thats where I got to install dotnet SDK and C#.

Comment: And you configured VSCode to be your external editor and open the script using double click from within Unity right?

Comment: @derHugo That's correct

Comment: Oh and intellisense is also installed? Honestly never worked with VSCode so far (I have heard it is a pain in the *** to set it up correctly :'D ) .. so just wanted to rule out the most obvious stuff

Comment: @derHugo I am not sure actually, but I think yes. I cannot see any "Intellisense" extension that looks default enough to install, and I had the idea that inteliisense is already part of VS Code. Quick google says to invoke it by CTRL+Space, which works and suggests things. All things suggested are marked as "abc", which I think means its a word gathered from elsewhere in script, not a snippet or function. Words like "before", "called", "class" shows up

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for along time but I think it is because Unity are using UnityScript So it is very similar to c# But in Unity There is some little different I think this is why it is not working .

**SOLUTION 1:**

try downloading Unity snippets extension Just Go To

File>Preferences>extensions

type Unity And Download these 3 extensions I find it more better than the original c# extension

[image: Unity extensions]

Here is The Links

[Unity Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YclepticStudios.unity-snippets)

[Unity Code Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kleber-swf.unity-code-snippets)

[Unity Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tobiah.unity-tools)

**SOLUTION 2:**

If none of the above Worked then the best solution is to download the [Visual Studio IDE from Microsoft](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/)

Delete VS Code you have and download the Microsoft version [Link above] And Then you can Choose to download the Unity package from the start menu. so no need to download any extensions ..... This Is The Best Solution for your problem there is no fix Just Download And That's it

Comment: I tried installing those three extensions and reloading VSCode (while disabling all other extensions). When I start typing Debug, and ask for completion after typing "Deb", I get "double", "DictionaryBase", "OnDisable()", "OnDisable()". 
I am confused, why does the editor still have no clue class Debug exists?

Comment: @Maximus What is your VS Code Version

Comment: I Updated My answer check the solution 2 @Maximus

Comment: my VSCode version is 1.60.2. I never used Visual Studio IDE, was hoping to save myself the jump. I will probably try it now, thanks.j

Answer (score 0):

Try following the steps in this link 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense

Comment: Is this compatible with VSCode?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, you can't open C# files by double clicking in Unity, this will work in visuals studio but not visual studio code

Instead right click on an empty space on your project tab and you should find an option for "Open C# project" press on that (you need to make sure that vs code is your default external code editing tool) and you are good to go

Additionally, you need to make sure you have the C# extension and you installed all required C# stuff like .NET framework, mono, or whatever

little tip: install unity tools and unity snippets extensions for better experience

if it didn't work what is your OS?

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this problem, and fix it by following [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity).

Here is my steps:

1. In Unity Editor, go to Window/Package Manager.
2. Click "Packages: In Project" combobox, and select "Unity Registry".
3. Search Visual Studio Code Editor and install.
4. Then go to Edit/Preferences, find External Tools on the left.
5. Change External Script Editor to where your vscode installed.
6. Click ""Regenerate project files".
7. In VSCode, Install C# Extension.

(Close vscode)
Now open a c# file from Unity, and see bottom of your vscode. ([the OmniSharp fire and Analyzing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wdFJ.png))

If it works you will see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2KyW.png).
And your intellisense should work now.

If not there maybe:

1. You cannot find the fire icon. -> It means your OmniSharp server is not running.
2. Error running the project. -> Click on OnmiSharp fire icon, and it will show errors.

PS. I'm using Unity 2021.3.5f1

PS2. Stackoverfolow not allow me to post a image.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project settings/external tools and set the visualstudiocode.exe as the script editor

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure the `C# extention` in `VSCode` is uninstalled
- Kill any `VSCode` process using the `Task Manager` (ctrl+shift+esc in Windows)
- Install the `dotnet SDK` from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download
- Locate your `dotnet` using `where.exe dotnet` command in a `cmd`
- Add the address that you get to the system `path`. follow [this link](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/#:%7E:text=Under%20the%20%E2%80%9CSystem%20Variables%E2%80%9D%20section,also%20edit%20or%20reorder%20them.)
- Reboot your device
- In `VSCode`, install `C# extention`
- In Unity -> edit -> preferences -> external tools, set `External Script Editor` to `Visual Studio Code`
- Hit `Regenerate Project Files` button
- Now open a script file from inside Unity and see if it's fixed